# How to clear all textfield of jframe using loop?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jtextarea

I'm developing Java application using NetBeans. I have 5 `JTextFields` and 2 `JTextArea` in `JFrame`. I want to clear them at once using a loop. How can it be done?

Comment: use `.getContentPane().getComponents()` on JFrame to get an array of its children.  Iterate that array, and for every item check `instanceOf TextComponent` if so, call `setText(null)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate over all of the components and set the text of all `JTextField` and `JTextArea` objects to an empty String:

```
//Note: "this" should be the Container that directly contains your components
//(most likely a JPanel).
//This won't work if you call getComponents on the top-level frame.
for (Component C : this.getComponents())
{    
    if (C instanceof JTextField || C instanceof JTextArea){

        ((JTextComponent) C).setText(""); //abstract superclass
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for being vague. The call to getComponents() should be made on a JPanel containing all of your components, not the top-level Frame, whose add(Component) method actually adds the Component to a JPanel nested inside of the JRootPane (therefore its getComponents() method will only return the JRootPane). I have tested this method and it works perfectly.

Comment: Didn't get it. It's not working , only returns JRootPane. I have tried this on JFrame... Any suggestions? Component[] components = jframe.getRootPane().getComponents();

Comment: @qwfddq As I explained in the above comments, you need to call `getComponents()` on the the Container to which you have added the components. This should not be the top-level frame.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate code should be this one

```
    Component[] components = jframe.getContentPane().getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        if (component instanceof JTextField || component instanceof JTextArea) {
            JTextComponent specificObject = (JTextComponent) component;
            specificObject.setText("");
        }
    }
```