# Clearing all JTextFields through Function

Tags: java, swing

I require a `static` `method` which I can keep in any `public` `class`, in which I will pass the object of an `JInternalFrame` and it will automatically clear all TextFields (using loop) of the particular `JInternalFrame`..

I have already gone through much answers, but they simply state using `setText("")` individually for all the TextFields, but thats not productive, simply because in my project i am planning 50 forms and more than 500 TextFields..

It will be helpful if anyone provides me with Snippets that has comments too so i can understand the working and implement for other components like checkboxes,radio etc on my own

Comment: how do you populate data in those textfields? Are those bind with some model object? If yes then you can simply reset model object.

Comment: No They are not binded , the textFields ie textboxes are normal fields for user input .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097626/ duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it short and simple.

**Class with static function:**

```
public class JCTest
{
    public static void Clear(JInternalFrame intFrame)
    {
        if (intFrame == null)
            return;
        Container con = intFrame.getContentPane();
        for (Component c : con.getComponents())
        {
            if (c instanceof JTextField)
            {
                JTextField j = (JTextField)c;
                j.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Call it:**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JInternalFrame intFrame = new JInternalFrame();
        JCTest.Clear(intFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u edit it a bit? I mean can u modify it so that i can put this into a class as static method and pass object of JinternalFrame to it and it clears all? The code is good i place it in same frame.. can u modify it?

Comment: Works like an Charm , Much easy to understand too , Implemented it myself for combobox too :) . When ever my rep is enough to give votes i will Definitely give to this answer :)

Comment: @RajitBansal You can always accept the answer you like. There's a button for this below the voting.

Comment: Can u please also tell me code if , my internal frame has some jpanels containing JtextFields , how can i make this function work on them

Comment: No need, i made the changes :)

Comment: Finally it works. been looking around and eveyone had it as 
for (Component c : this.getComponents())

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can call getComponents() Method that will return all child components. Then you have to check whether it of type JTextField and then you can call .setText("") on it. If you want a simmilar solution for all Swing Components you can work with Document, wich is an abstraction of the data that the compontent is showing. Here is an example:

```
if (rootComponent instanceof Container) {
    Component[] subComponents = ((Container) rootComponent).getComponents();
        for (Component c : subComponents) {
            if (c instanceof JTextField)
                c.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Edit this is from my project, I have split it in two method. ApplyColors, because I use it for coloring the components. I think it works with setText() as well.

```
public static void applyColors(Window parent) {
    List<String> colorComponentsClassNames = Arrays.asList("JTextField");
        for (Component component : getAllComponents(parent)) {
        Component[] components = ((Container) component).getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            Component currentComponent = components[i];
            if (!colorComponentsClassNames.contains(currentComponent.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                continue;
            }
            currentComponent.setText(""));

        }
    }
}

public static List<Component> getAllComponents(final Container c) {
    Component[] comps = c.getComponents();
    List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>();
    for (Component comp : comps) {
        compList.add(comp);
        if (comp instanceof Container) {
            compList.addAll(getAllComponents((Container) comp));
        }
    }
    return compList;
}
```

Comment: Can u modify the same if i want to use it in other class which i am using it for global functions, in which i can pass the Form or rootCompnent as parameter?

Comment: Well thats was the question @MadProgrammer. Just pass in the JInternalFrame.

Comment: `JInternalFrame` is a `Container`, which contains a `JRootPane`, which is `Container`, which contains a  "content pane", which is `Container`, which could container one or more other `Container`s...gets messy quickly...This could also clear fields that the OP doesn't really want cleared, it's a bit like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly, works, but it's messy and you tend to break other things you didn't mean to ;)

Comment: Well i am okay with it works as i will manually clear for the forms which have few fields i dont wanna empty.. let me test this now.

Comment: Stimpson Cat , Can u please provide me with accurate function which i can directly copy paste and check?

Comment: @RajitBansal Try some effort first before you go asking for "copy and paste" solutions, we don't have enough context to always generate 100% working solutions to problems, nor are we your code monkeys.  Start by refering to the JavaDocs [Container#getComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents())

Comment: Brilliant code @StimpsonCat , it also gave me answer how to automatically add all components in a list .. Will keep it in my snippents collection.

Answer (score 1):

## You Could...

Use [`Container#getComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) to list all the child components of a given `Container`, you would need to check each `Component` and test to see if it was an `instanceof` `JTextField`, when you find a component that is, cast it and use `setText` to clear the field.  You would also need to test each `Component` to see if it was an `instanceof` `Container` and perform a recursive search, as `getComponents` will only return the immediate children of the specified `Container`

This is kind of messy and time consuming, as you need to walk the entire component hierarchy in order to be sure you find all the fields.  It also means that it would clear fields you actually don't want to clear...

## You Could...

Create a custom class, extending from `JInternalFrame` or some other class like `JPanel`, which had a method called `clearFields` (for example), which could simply loop through a `List` of `JTextField`s.

You would need to add each field you want managed by this method to the `List`, but it would be a simpler mechanism...

```
public class MyAwesomeForm extends JPanel {
    private List<JTextField> fields;
    
    public void registerField(JTextField field) {
        fields.add(field);
    }

    public void unregisterField(JTextField field) {
        fields.remove(field);
    }

    public void clearFields() {
        for (JTextField field : fields) {
            field.setText(null);
        }
    }
}
```

All your forms would then need to extend from this and when required, you would simply call `clearFields` for a given form...

Comment: Basically for projects i use netbeans and it wont automatically add all components to list, and doing it manually will consume much time .. any other code without using LIST

Comment: Well I think first approach is better ... because why should we waste memory (using 2nd approach) by registering/storing `jtextfield`(s) if the container do maintain it for us !! And first approach is not messy ...

Comment: @Junaid Because it's like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly, it might work, but you tend to break more things in the process. The first suggestion also doesn't allow you to "filter" the process to avoid resetting fields that you may not want cleared.  It's also using a recursive method, which is filling up the stack, so if you're worried about memory, the second approach is actually cheaper and quicker.

Comment: @RajitBansal Then you're shooting yourself in the foot, however, you can use custom components in the form editor, so the second solution would still be feasible, you'd simply have to figure out how to get the fields into the `List` ;) - Remember, you're dealing with a OO language, you should be focusing and using it to reduce duplication and repetition...

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer, if we talk about memory then his approach is better , but for this particular one i want to clear all the textfields so no filtering is needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer the first approach may not be recursive ... you can do it using loops !!

Comment: @Junaid And the second solution can be done with a single loop using less iterations ...